# Trouble connecting raspberry pi to laptop

Tags: newbie

I am new to raspberry pi, I am following this tutorial [https://beebom.com/how-use-windows-laptop-as-monitor-raspberry-pi/#:~:text=Use%20the%20ethernet%20cable%20and,port%20as%20a%20power%20source](https://beebom.com/how-use-windows-laptop-as-monitor-raspberry-pi/#:%7E:text=Use%20the%20ethernet%20cable%20and,port%20as%20a%20power%20source). I get to the point where I can open putty but when I type in the default password, "raspberry" it says access denied.

How to log into my raspberry pi from my laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That article in the link was written before a security change was made to Raspberry Pi OS quite recently (April 2022). For most of the Pi's history, there was a default user, `pi`, and a default password for that user, `raspberry`. This was recognised as a security risk, and releases of Bullseye Raspberry Pi OS now make you create a user name and password at first run (if you are using a monitor/keyboard/mouse connected to the Pi) or if you want to use it headless via ssh (e.g. with a terminal app like Putty) you can use the Raspberry Pi Imager tool to create the SD or micro SD card, and set up username and password before the card is flashed.

[An update to Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye 7 April 2022](https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/raspberry-pi-bullseye-update-april-2022/)

[Raspberry Pi OS Imager](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the PI with a monitor and keyboard first. Do all updates.

If you put this in the search engine, "problem with raspberry pi putty password" you will see there are many issues. But I would get it working well on the monitor first.

Other people have reported this problem. https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=94011

Comment: I used a monitor instead, and it was much easier to work with it. Thank you!